# Unable to grab URL parameters using _GET

Tags: php, get, url-parameters

First time posting and I am fairly new at using PHP so please bare with me. If this needs further explanation, just let me know.

I have a page (let's call it **page1.php**) that has the following global variable declared:

```
$online = true;
```

When a link on **page1.php** is clicked, I want to pass a parameter (called **method**) to the following page (let's call it **page2.php**). If page2.php is accessed via a link from page1.php specifically, I want it to load with this parameter in place and trigger a certain behavior.

***Update: added on 3/16/21**
The link on page1.php is included in a template file that is used on multiple pages. So I have used a php if statement to append the parameter to the link if the page has a global variable of `$online = true`:*

```
<a href="page2.php<?php if(isset(GLOBALS['online'])) {?>?method=online<?php } ?>"?link</a>
```

So far, I have successfully (I think) passed the parameter to page2.php (**page2.php?method=online**). At the top of page2.php, I have the following code in place to assign the value of this parameter to a variable called `$method`:

```
$method = $_GET['method'];
```

I expected this to make `$method = "online"` but unfortunately, when I do this and try to `echo $method`, I get the following notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: method in
> C:URL\index.php on
> line 7

This seemed fairly straight forward when I started but this is driving me crazy. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you access page 2? Can you please share the code for that link?

Comment: So the link is included in a template file that is included on multiple pages. But if the global variable of $online = true on the page, I use a php if statement to append the parameter to the link as follows: I'll add this to my original post for formatting.

<a href="page2.php<?php if(isset(GLOBALS['online'])) {?>?method=online<?php } ?>"?link</a>

Comment: That has both PHP and HTML errors. It should be `$_GLOBALS` and you're missing a closing bracket for `<a>`.

Comment: Also, where exactly do you make `$online` global?

Comment: Sorry, I manually typed that out when I should have copy/pasted. Those html errors weren't included in the actual code. However, most documentation I have referenced doesn't include the _ in GLOBALS. 

<a href="<?= $step['link'] ?><?php if(isset($GLOBALS['online'])) {?>?method=online<?php } ?>">Link</a>

Comment: Also, I may be misunderstanding what actually makes a variable global. I have a php block at the top of my file (before the doctype is declared) where I set any php variables I want to use throughout the page. Since it was not declared inside a function, I just assumed it was global by default.

Comment: Well, there's your issue. That doesn't make it registered as a global. And you're right, it's `$GLOBALS`, without the underscore. It's a reflex from using `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: Setting that aside, there is no reason for you to declare it global. Just use it directly `if($online === true)`.

Answer (score 2):

this way works for me:

page1.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="page2.php?method=online">link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```php
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$method = false; // empty
if(array_key_exists('method', $_GET) and !empty($_GET['method']))
    $method = $_GET['method'];
var_dump($method);
// https://yoururl/page2.php?method=online 
// string(6) "online"
// https://yoururl/page2.php?method=
// bool(false)
// https://yoururl/page2.php
// bool(false)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the response. I tried this and it resulted in $method = false. In the URL, I can clearly see the parameter but nothing I have tried seems to recognize that it exists. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Someone else asked a question about the link on page1 is created so I have added some additional details in the original post if that helps.

Comment: I noticed that when I do `var_dump($_GET);` I get the following output:

`array(0) { }`

This seems to indicate that it is not recognizing any get variables in the URL even though *?method=online* is very clearly visible in the url.

Comment: Yes, it is empty because $GLOBALS['online'] is not set.  
var_dump($GLOBALS)

Comment: So I think that might be where i'm having the disconnect. How do I grab the value of method from the url and assign it to a global variable when the page loads? It's there in the URL but I can't seem to do anything with it.

Answer (score 2):

Update your code like this

```
// if it does not exist.
$method = $_GET['method'] ?? null;
```

[PHP Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)
Keep trying and play with the language, you are in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that when page2.php loads, it is not seeing the parameter at all. The code you provided will result in $method = null. But when I look in the URL, I clearly see ?method=online

Comment: Someone else asked a question about the link on page1 is created so I have added some additional details in the original post if that helps.

Comment: If the url contain `?method=online` the `$_GET['method']` return `online`

Comment: It is supposed to but it is not which is the crux of my issue. Despite seeing the parameter in the url, it is being declared as null.